# Domain=".hostimpl[... - how interpret this cookie?

Tags: cookies

how do I interpret domain in this cookie:

```
portal-referer=http%3A%2F%2Fservice.mail.com%2Fmcstarter%2Fmail.html%3F; Domain=".hostimpl[name=www.mail.com,domain=mail.com]"; Path=/
```

?

Maybe I have to add this cookie to CookieContainer (C#) assigned to uri "www.mail.com" and another copy of this cookie to uri "mail.com"?

Thanks